# Which is the telemetry format for the getforobserved method in Google Proximity Beacon API?

Tags: google-beacon-platform

I want to send beacon's eddystone telemetry when calling the getforobserved method of Google proximity beacon api.

The documentation isn't clear: https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/reference/rest/v1beta1/beaconinfo/getforobserved#Observation

For the telemetry field it states:

> The array of telemetry bytes received from the beacon. The server is responsible for parsing it. This field may frequently be empty, as with a beacon that transmits telemetry only occasionally.

What should i put in the json? Should i send only the TLM frame or the complete eddystone packet? Should i encode it using base64? Can someone point me to an example? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs don't say how the bytes should be encoded, but base64 is a reasonable assumption, given that's how [the beacon id is encoded](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/reference/rest/v1beta1/AdvertisedId).  So if you have a telemetry byte string that looks like this (bytes shown in hex):

```
2000000000080100000001000000
```

The Base 64 encoding would be:

```
IAAAAAAIAQAAAAEAAAA=
```

So you could try sending something like this:

```
{
...
  "telemetry": "IAAAAAAIAQAAAAEAAAA=",
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer david. I'm using your Android Beacon Library, it returns the telemetry fields as a List of long then i have to recreate the telemetry frame manually. Should i put in the json only this 14 bytes? [link](https://github.com/google/eddystone/tree/master/eddystone-tlm). Thank you

Comment: @Fabrizio, I have added an experimental utility that will let you access the Eddystone-TLM from the Android Beacon Library.  Please try this and let me know if it works for you.  If you can verify it solves your need, I can merge it into a formal release of the library.  https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/pull/328